# Calling function inside another function returns unexpected value while calling first function directly returns expected value

Tags: python, function

I have written multiple functions that when I call them directly, they result as expected. This is the function:

```
def number_generator():
    for number in range(1, 815+1):
        file = open('numbers.txt', 'a')
        file.write(f'{number}\n')
        file.close()
```

It writes numbers from 1 to 815 without problem.

But when I call this function inside another function, it returns unexpected value. This is the other function:

```
def test():
    file1 = open('file1.txt', 'a')
    file1.write(f'{query_generator()}{number_generator()}\'\n')
    file1.close()
```

The current result is `NoneNone'`.

`query_generator` generates 815 times one SQL query in 815 lines, and `number_generator` generates number for ID of each my website products.

But when I use them inside `test` function I do not get the expected value.

**What I did so far** is I removed the lines related to `file` variable related to `number_generator` and `query_generator`, and added a `return` statement inside both of them but that did not work.

**My expected value is like something below:**

```
UPDATE `tblpricing` SET `msetupfee` = '1'
UPDATE `tblpricing` SET `msetupfee` = '2'
UPDATE `tblpricing` SET `msetupfee` = '3'
```

How may I reach it?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a function that doesn't return anything into an f string. You noted that you added a `return` statement, but I am just going to assume that it was just a `return` followed by nothing else, seeing that that still didn't work. See this simple demo:

```
def add(a, b):
    result = a+b
    return
```

```
a = 1
b = 4
print(f'{a} + {b} is {add(a, b)}')
```

Output:

```
1 + 4 is None
```

Why? Because there is no return value in `add()`. If we change`add()` to:

```
def add(a, b):
    result = a+b
    return result
```

The output is:

```
1 + 4 is 5
```

You have not shown what your `query_generator()` function looks like so without seeing that function, we cannot say if there is another issue than just a missing return value. This line is your culprit:

```
file1.write(f'{query_generator()}{number_generator()}\'\n')
```

`number_generator()` doesn't return anything, it just opens a file and writes the numbers 1 to 815. To solve your issue, create two functions: one for writing the file and one for reading it. I suggest implementing `with open()` instead of just `open()`. Also, your current `number_generator()` opens a file, writes one line, and closes that file 815 times which you probably don't want. Do this instead:

```
def number_generator():
    with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as file:
        for number in range(1, 816):
            file.write(f'{number}\n')

def get_numbers():
    with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in file]
        return lines

def query_generator():
    # logic for query generator here

def get_queries():
    # get queries
    # IMPORTANT: Return queries as a list
```

Note that in `get_queries()`, the return type should be a list. This is so you can easily iterate and compare both the queries and the numbers simultaneously.
Your function could then look like this:

```
def test():
    # write queries and numbers
    query_generator()
    number_generator()

    # read queries and numbers
    queries = get_queries()
    numbers = get_numbers()

    # zip queries and numbers
    lines = zip(queries, numbers)

    # open file and write each line
    with open('file1.txt', 'w') as file:
        for line in lines:
            comp_line = f'{line[0]} = {line[1]}\n'
            file.write(comp_line)
```

This gets you your desired output:

```
UPDATE `tblpricing` SET `msetupfee` = '1'
UPDATE `tblpricing` SET `msetupfee` = '2'
UPDATE `tblpricing` SET `msetupfee` = '3'
...
```